# How to handle maps with no key match

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having a map and want to expose it in the VF page and I did something like below

```
list<related_object__c> related_object_list =[select decimal_field__c from related_object__c limit 1];
    Map<id,decimal> map_string_id = new map <id,string>();
    for(opportunity o: [select id from opportunity where account!= null]{
for(related_object__c rel: related_object_list){
    map_string_id.put(opp.id,rel.decimal_field__c); } }
```

The page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="opportunity">
<apex:form>
<apex:repeat value="{!opportunity}" var="opp">
<apex:outputtext value="{!map_string_id[opp]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The problem is that the map may or may not contain the opportunityID based my query in the controller and gives me

```
Map key 006.... not found in map
```

Is there a way to check in the VF page if the map containsKey ?
I want to see if there is any way I can do  something like :

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!map_string_id[opp]}" rendered="**{!map_string_id.containsKey(opp)}**/>
```

Is this possible !!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not possible to check whether a Map in your controller has a key in it from your VF page in a dynamic fashion in the way you are doing. Your best bet is to either

change your repeat to iterate over the keys of the map:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!map_string_id.keys}" var="key">
<apex:outputtext value="{!map_string_id[key]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

create a wrapper class that checks if an opportunity is in the map:

```
public class oppWrapper
{
    public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
    public Boolean isInMap(){return map_string_id.containskey(opp.ID);}
}
```

and the visualforce:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!oppWrappers}" var="wrapper">
<!--some other fields from the opportunity-->
<apex:outputtext rendered="{!wrapper.isInMap}" value="{!map_string_id[wrapper.opp]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

For small sets you can just nest apex:repeat controls and render when the items are equal:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="opportunity">
   <apex:form>
      <apex:repeat value="opportunity" var='opp'>
         <apex:repeat value="{!map_string_id}" var="x">
             <apex:outputtext rendered="{!opp.id == x.id}" value="{!map_string_id[x]}"/>
         </apex:repeat>
      </apex:repeat>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It's not efficient (~n^2), but it works well for small sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all keys of the map to a string and then use the string to render the section where the map is used in vf page.