# How to check check Map is Empty or null in Visualforce page dynamically in <apex:repeat>

Tags: apex

I already referred link : **[How to handle maps with no key match](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/how-to-handle-maps-with-no-key-match)** and unable to implement logic something simillar, because every time I am getting fields in a Map is dynamic.

I have a below logic

```
public Map<String,sObject> TInfoDetails {get; set;}
public Map<String,String> tFieldList;
.........
.........
........

public void gettInfo(){
    if(tFieldList != null){
        for(String objectName : tFieldList.keyset()){
            String queryStr = 'SELECT Id,' + tFieldList.get(objectName)) + ' FROM '+objectName+' WHERE Case__c = ' + '\'' + currentCase.Id + '\'' LIMIT 1'; 
            List<Sobject> value = Database.query(queryStr);
            if(value  != null && !value .isEmpty()){
                TInfoDetails.put(objectName,value[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's always not necessary that this MAP will always populate, when I am iterating through that Map like below I see the **"Transaction__c map key not found"**.

```
public map<Decimal, List<Transaction__c>> tFieldsConfigMap {get;set;}
public map<Decimal, Transaction__c> tSectionMap {get;set;}
public Map<String,sObject> tInfoDetails {get; set;}

<apex:repeat value="{!tFieldsConfigMap}" var="map1">

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!IF( tSectionMap[map1].Section__c != 1, tSectionMap[map1].SectionLabel__c,'')}" columns="{!tSectionMap[map1].ColumnsPerSection__c}" rendered="{!tSectionMap[map1].SectionName__c != 'ABC'}">           

        <apex:repeat value="{!tFieldsConfigMap[map1]}" var="map2">      
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!map2.Object__c != 'XXXX'}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!map2.FieldLabel__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!tInfoDetails[map2.Object__c][map2.FieldNameAPI__c]}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try checking rendered="{!NOT(mapIsEmpty)}"

Comment: Not working at all